# Create new column using row-wise operations in Data.Table R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables in R as follows:

`DT_A` with columns `sid`, `date`, `value1`, `value2`, where `sid` is a primary key and `date` is a secondary key.

`DT_B` has columns `sid`, `date1`, `date2`, `date3`,  ...., `date12`. Here `sid` is the primary key and hence each row corresponds to the unique `sid` and the other column names correspond to secondary keys in `DT_A`.

I want to add another column to `DT_A` where the ith row contains the corresponding element from the table DT_B[sid_i, date_i]

Below is the example code and the desired output:

```
require(data.table)
DT_A <- data.table(sid = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,3), 
                   date = c("Jan 2012", "Feb 2012", "April 2012", "May 2012", 
                            "Dec 2012", "Feb   2012", "Oct 2012"),
                   value1 = rep("1", 7), 
                   value2 = rep("1", 7))

DT_B <- data.table(sid = as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5)), 
                   "Jan 2012" = rep("1", 5),
                   "Feb 2012" = rep("2", 5),
                   "March 2012" = rep("3", 5),
                   "April 2012" = rep("4", 5),
                   "May 2012" = rep("5", 5),
                   "June 2012" = rep("6", 5),
                   "July 2012" = rep("7", 5),
                   "Aug          2012" = rep("8", 5),
                   "Sept 2012" = rep("9", 5),
                   "Oct 2012" = rep("10", 5),
                   "Nov 2012" = rep("11", 5),
                   "Dec 2012" = rep("12", 5))

#Set Keys
setkey(DT_A, sid, date)
setkey(DT_B, sid)

#Define Function fun1
fun1 <- function(x){ 
    tryCatch(DT_B[x[1], x[2], with=FALSE], error = function(e) NULL)
}

#Desired Output
DT_A$newCol <- sapply(apply(DT_A, 1, fun1),"[[",1)
DT_A
```

Although my current method works on this small example, my actual DT_A has 20 million rows. This method completely hangs there. Can we do this operation in a more efficient way using `data.table` or any other method?

Comment: You didn't provide `DT_A`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, have done that now

Comment: I think the question should be reworded.  This is not about doing row wise operations, this is about reshaping and merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Melt your second `data.table`:

```
library(reshape2)

DT_B.melted = melt(DT_B, id.vars = 'sid', variable.name = 'date')
```

Once it's melted, you can set both to the same key, and do your join/assign/whatnot:

```
setkey(DT_B.melted, sid, date)
setkey(DT_A, sid, date)

DT_A[DT_B.melted, newCol := value]
```

Comment: I think you"ll need to add `DT_B.melted[,sid:= as.numeric(sid)]` after melting, otherwise it return error (for me atleast)

Comment: @DavidArenburg you're right - but I assume that the class mismatch is just a mistake in the OP (i.e. that should probably be fixed upstream, before the melting even begins)

Comment: Wow... this works like a breeze, I did not know about the melt function... thanks a lot...